# Any good suggestions for Basys2 optional oscillator 50 MHz or 100 MHz?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, crystal, intel-fpga

I want to get the optional stable oscillator for the Basys-2 but don't know which would be the best choice for 50 MHz and 100 MHz? Has anyone bought and used any? If so, what is the part number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basys 2 already has integrated [LTC6905](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6905) oscillator (IC5) that can be controlled with a jumper (JP4). You can easily obtain 100MHz, 50MHz or 25MHz just by soldering the jumper, so I would just recommend doing this. This silicon oscillator is connected to input B8 of FPGA. For most applications it will be more flexible to just use the integrated oscillator.

In a few special situations you might want to install the optional second oscillator. For example if the frequency you need is not easily obtainable by dividing the one from integrated oscillator, or when you need a signal of greater stability (LTC6905 is not very stable). Note that the second oscillator is connected to a separate input M6, so you can use both of them at the same time.

The example part number for 50MHz oscillator would be ABRACON ACHL-50.000MHZ-EK.

Of course the question what exact frequency you need depends on your application. You never explained what do you intend to do with your Basys 2 board.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for very high stability clock. That's why I asked for the optional oscillator.

Comment: I edited my answer a moment ago to include example part number that would be good. But any 3.3V half-size DIP oscillator with the same pinout would fit.